# How to import and sync a BitBucket project

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I've seen a lot of guides about creating an Android Studio project and adding it onto BitBucket as a Git repository, but what about the opposite?

I have a friend whose app I want to contribute to and he gave me access to it on BitBucket but I can't seem to understand how to take the branch that I have and sync it with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Go to bitbucket and open that repo. Click on clone button. You will get something like git clone . Copy that whole line and paste in your Terminal and enter. It will start downloading. After downloading done..open your android studio and go to file->open->path where project downloaded->select build.gradle file from project and open it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your profile in BitBucket, navigate to the repository. There you will find a code starts with ***git clone...*** in that code you will find a URL (The url of your BitBucket repository), **copy that url only**.

Now come back to your Android Studio and close all project from `file==>close project.`

Now, navigate : `check out project from version control ==> Git ==> paste the URL (of BitBucket repository) in the text area of Git repository URL ==> clone.`

All set and you are done.